# why i got the error "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am inserting data from `datagridview` into database , I debug my code and found the error Input string was not in a correct format. in the following line

```
Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString())
```

this column is an integer column and when i replaced this line with integer value for example number 3 insert completed without errors , and the other integer columns also inserted same way without any error 
this is my code :

```
    if (checkApproveResult.Checked == false && chkupdateApproved.Checked == false)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        result.UPDATE_LAB_RESULTS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
                                                  5,
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                                                  txtExamUser.Text,
                                                  DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString()),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(txtcustid.Text),
                                                  txtReqForm.Text,
                                                  dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                                                  Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString()));
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Result Saved Successfully ", "Entering Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }

   else if (chkupdateApproved.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        result.ADD_LAB_RESULTS_UPDATES(Convert.ToInt32(txtsampleid.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtgroupid.Text),
                            "YES",
                            6,
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString(),
                            DateTime.Parse(DateTimeExamined.Value.ToString()),
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString(),
                            DateTime.Parse(dateTimeApprove.Value.ToString()),
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                            dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtpackageid.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString()),
                            2,
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtPno.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtcustid.Text), txtReqForm.Text, 
                            Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString()),
                            txtupdatedby.Text,
                            DateTime.Parse(dateupdate.Value.ToString()));

                        }
                    update.UPDATE_LAB_RESULT_STATUS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtsampleid.Text), 2);
                    MessageBox.Show("Result Updated Successfully ", "Update Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

And the code for ADD_LAB_RESULT_UPDATES was :

```
public void ADD_LAB_RESULTS_UPDATES(int SAMPLE_ID, int ORDER_ID,int TESTID,int GROUPID, string NORMAL_RESULT, 
            int SAMPLE_STATUS,string EXAMINED_BY,DateTime EXAMINED_DATE, string APPROVED_BY, DateTime APPROVED_DATE,
            string RESULT_NUMBER, string RESULT_REPORT, string RESULT_NOTE,int packageid, int machine_id, int deptid, 
            int patient_no, int custid, string REQ_FORM_NO,int serial,string UPDATED_BY,DateTime UPDATED_DATE)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[22];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@SAMPLE_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[0].Value = SAMPLE_ID;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ORDER_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[1].Value = ORDER_ID;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@TESTID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[2].Value = TESTID;

            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@GROUPID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[3].Value = GROUPID;

            param[4] = new SqlParameter("@NORMAL_RESULT", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
            param[4].Value = NORMAL_RESULT;

            param[5] = new SqlParameter("@SAMPLE_STATUS", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[5].Value = SAMPLE_STATUS;

            param[6] = new SqlParameter("@EXAMINED_BY", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[6].Value = EXAMINED_BY;

            param[7] = new SqlParameter("@EXAMINED_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[7].Value = EXAMINED_DATE;

            param[8] = new SqlParameter("@APPROVED_BY", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[8].Value = APPROVED_BY;

            param[9] = new SqlParameter("@APPROVED_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[9].Value = APPROVED_DATE;

            param[10] = new SqlParameter("@RESULT_NUMBER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[10].Value = RESULT_NUMBER;

            param[11] = new SqlParameter("@RESULT_REPORT", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
            param[11].Value = RESULT_REPORT;

            param[12] = new SqlParameter("@RESULT_NOTE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
            param[12].Value = RESULT_NOTE;

            param[13] = new SqlParameter("@packageid", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[13].Value = packageid;

            param[14] = new SqlParameter("@machine_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[14].Value = machine_id;

            param[15] = new SqlParameter("@deptid", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[15].Value = deptid;

            param[16] = new SqlParameter("@patient_no", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[16].Value = patient_no;

            param[17] = new SqlParameter("@custid", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[17].Value = custid;

            param[18] = new SqlParameter("@REQ_FORM_NO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[18].Value = REQ_FORM_NO;

            param[19] = new SqlParameter("@serial", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[19].Value = serial;

            param[20] = new SqlParameter("@UPDATED_BY", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[20].Value = UPDATED_BY;

            param[21] = new SqlParameter("@UPDATED_DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[21].Value = UPDATED_DATE;

            DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_LAB_RESULTS_UPDATES", param);
            DAL.close();

        }
```

the error with parameter 14 `machine_id`
also the table in the `database machine_id int`.

What is the error ?

More information I have first if statement (update statement) 
result. `UPDATE_LAB_RESULTS` includes same parameter machine_id and its working and inserting without errors. 
Second if statement (insert statement) and show the error with `machine_id` parameter.

Comment: What is the content of the value that cased error? Are you sure there is no group separator used in the value? There is probably not a number _(meaning only digits)_. Or the number is too big _(bigger then Int32)_.

Comment: The DGV cell is probably null and you can't put a null into an 'int'.  You can use 'int?' instead.  I suspect you have the DGV set to Edit Mode which create a Blank line at end of DGV.  So you probably want "dgvResult.Rows.Count - 1"  (I added the minus 1).

Comment: @Julo the content was integer numbers between 1 and 20 machine id only digits.

Comment: @jdweng I added dgvResult.Rows.Count - 1 but same error , where to use 'int?' , the cell always have value machine id between 1 and 20 and i edit the cell by this value .

Comment: @Abdullah are you sure? Did you check the value that caused the error? I already saw many problems that were caused because of assumptions.

Comment: @Julo yes i am sure i replaced all the values with fixed values numbers , string values and dates then i returned it one by one and finally i catched the error with this line Convert.ToInt32(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString().  when i used number 3 its saving when i returned the code i got the error , what do you mean by assumptions?

Comment: e.g. I assume that the value will be always number and only number. But when reading from database you read ' 3', or '3 ' _(with space)_ and not '3'. This is the behaviour of databases _(OK, it is only for strings when defined in a standard way, as "string(length)", but when you check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, because you stored an empty string, you will be surprised... Simply there are people that assume the result, but do not consider other possibilities)_

Comment: @julo I have 2 if statement with first one machine_id same parameter updating the database without error but second if statement (insert command) show the error when inserting , I updated my code with both if statement.

Comment: This is really hard to say where is the problem. I personally do not use initialisations that are on too many lines. It is hard to determine what statement caused the error and also, why the order of elements is like this. I would use many simple initialisations (to local variables) and then use these as initialisation. This way you can better determine the error position. In current case _(when you are sure that the error line is known)_. In the code there are 3 unique int parse and 2 date time parse methods. The only other option I can think of is change current culture for one thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the following :

1- check the parameter list variables types (string , int , ...) and compare it with your procedure you will find one variable type different in the stored procedure integer and in the parameter list string.